# Catching sys.exit

Tags: c++

Hi to all =)
I've a little curiosity
If I've the following function, that close the program calling sys.exit:

```
void stop(int state){
    std::exit(state);
}
```

Now, I want to call this function, but without exit the program.
So, I want to "catch" the std::exit command... is there a method to do it?

Comment: What do you mean by "catching"? It's not an exception. If you want to add some code that will prevent calling exit, can't you just wrap it somehow?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do the same as with tail recursion: Have the offending function call always be the last statement in the execution path, or not occur at all:

```
void stop(int state)
{
  const bool exitReally = DecideWhetherToExit();
  if (exitReally)
    std::exit(state);
}
```

This function will never do anything after calling `std::exit`, but might also not call it at all, decided after evaluating whatever you want in another function, for example.

Answer (score 1):

You can't do this, because `exit` is guaranteed to never return. As a result the compiler can take advantage of this and generate code that doesn't have any execution path after `exit`. If `exit` returns by some hackery, you'll get undefined-behavior. So there is no standard way for this.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, you can't call `exit` and then further prevent the application from terminating.

Can you not just pass in another parameter to `stop` so that it doesn't call `exit` ?

E.g.

```
void stop(int state, bool exit)
{
    if(exit)
        std::exit(state);
}
```